# Kernel, variance and estimation

Tags: reference-request, variance, estimation

In the paper by Terrell 1990, in the Theorem 1 below on the page 471,
I would like to derive the formulas for $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ and perhaps also why $\beta(k+2,k+2)$ minimizes that integral given.Why there is no $\sigma^2$ nor in $g$ nor in $h(x)$: $g(x)$ is given as $\frac{15}{16}(1-x^2)^2$ therefore we cannot just assume that it has that specific variance!

[image]

**APPENDIX**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, if you have access to the full article, you might want to look at the Appendix as the paper claims to provide the requisite proof therein.  As I do not have access, I don't know.

Regarding your question about how neither $g$ nor $h$ contain $\sigma$, I should point out that when they say "member of the scale family," they are saying that there is an entire family of distributions parametrized by a scaling factor, say $a > 0$; e.g.,
$$g(x \mid a) = \frac{15}{16a} \left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)^2, \quad |x| \le a,$$
whose relationship with the variance is given by $\sigma^2 = a^2/7$, which allows us to specify an arbitrary width for $g$ with the desired properties.  In other words, the author is giving you a "canonical" or "standard" form for these.

Comment: Please, before accepting your answer, tell me how have you arrived at $a^2/7$. See my edited question for Appendix.

Comment: @user122424 It's really difficult to read the image, so I didn't check the proof in detail.  But regarding your question, it is simply a matter of computing $$\int_{x=-a}^a x^2 g(x \mid a) \, dx = \frac{a^2}{7},$$ and noting that due to symmetry, $$\int_{x=-a}^a x g(x \mid a) \, dx = 0.$$  Hence the variance of $g(X \mid a)$ is $a^2/7$, so if we want a particular variance $\sigma^2$, then we would choose $a = \sigma \sqrt{7}$.

Comment: Would you mind doing the calculation from your first integral for a beginner?esp. I'm unable to treat $g(x|a)$ and integrate it properly.